# Sitecore 7 Media Framework tab not visible

Tags: sitecore, brightcove

We have migrated brightcove from one environment to another by taking items related to brightcove from the existing environment and moving files manually.

However in the new environment brightcove seem to be working(I tested brightcove import/export/cleanup by adding those buttons to MyToolbar as shown in screenshot 2) except for the below issue.

Issue: ”Media Framework tab is not visible in the ribbon”

Screenshot 1

[image]

ScreenShot 2

[image]

Can you help me on this? Any idea on how to enable that tab?

Package Details are as below:

1. Sitecore Media Framework rev. 130924.zip

Items in the above package:

core\sitecore\content\Applications\Content Editor\Menues\Media Framework
core\sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Media Framework
core/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Strips/Media Framework
core/sitecore/content/Applications/Media/MediaFramework
core/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Buttons/Embed Media
core/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Media/EmbedMedia
core/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Media/Uploader
core//sitecore/system/Field types/MediaFramework
core/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/Toolbar 1/Embed Link
core/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/Toolbar 1/Embed Media
core/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/Toolbar 1/Embed Media
core/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/Toolbar 1/Embed Link
master/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/embedMedia
master/sitecore/layout/Sublayouts/Media Framework
master/sitecore/media library/Media Framework
master/sitecore/system/Modules/Media Framework
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/Media Framework
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Reports/Reports/Media Framework
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Reports SQL Queries/Most Completed Videos
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Reports SQL Queries/Most Popular Videos Started But Not Completed
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Reports SQL Queries/Most Started Videos
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Settings/Quick Actions/Media Preview
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Command Rules/Actions/Set Command State
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Command Rules/Command State Rules
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Command Rules/Rules
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Common/Conditions/Media Framework
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Rules/Clear Media Framework Rules Cache
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/MediaFramework
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/Media Framework
master/sitecore/templates/Branches/Media Framework
master/sitecore/templates/MediaFramework
master/sitecore/templates/System/Rules/CommandStateRule

2. Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove rev. 130924.zip

Items in the above package:

core/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Media Framework
core/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Media Framework
master/sitecore/system/Modules/Media Framework
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Command Rules/Rules
master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules/MediaFramework Brightcove
master/sitecore/templates/Branches/Media Framework

Thanks,
Suhas

Comment: Have you check if the tab items exist in the core database?

Comment: Hi Maras,I extracted the bright cove package and made a list of all items in brightcove package and then took them into seperate package.I have updated the list in my query as well.I dont see any tab item in the list?Can you please let me know which item you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the **/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Ribbons/Default/Media Framework** item.

Answer (score 1):

Use AccessViewer and see which role is denying read access to  "/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Ribbons/Default/Media Framework" and "/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Media Framework" items in core DB.

I found read access to "/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Media Framework" is denied for "Sitecore client users" role, assigning read access to Media Framework chunk item and its descends fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to give an almost link-only-answer, but Maras is right. You haven't migrated the Sitecore user interface customisations, tools and commands across. These all live in the "core" database.

Mark Stiles has a blogpost that describes the Brightcove files and items in detail, here: http://www.markstiles.net/Blog/2011/03/16/brightcove-in-sitecore.aspx

Look for this section "Inside Sitecore itself there are also a good number of items that you should know about. First in the core are the content editor tabs. These are pretty essential to giving the end user a good UI to work with when they want to view a preview a video in a player or edit an item or even add images to a video. I'll go more into what those look like further into the article."